# How can I sort my processes by name?

Tags: c#

This is my code and I would like to know how I can put this in an alphabetical list. Thanks!

```
Process[] proc;

void GetAllProcess()
{
    proc = Process.GetProcesses();
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Process p in proc)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
    }
}


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetAllProcess();
}
```

Comment: Using the [IEnumerable extension OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

LINQ makes it really easy to work with collections of things and it has an `OrderBy` option. Once you have them ordered you can again use LINQ to `Select` the process name of each and then use those names and use `Select` to insert them into the list.

```
proc = Process.GetProcesses()
    .OrderBy(p => p.ProcessName)
    .ToArray();
proc.Select(p => p.ProcessName)
    .Select(listBox1.Items.Add);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this, I've modified your function:

```
void GetAllProcess()
{
    proc = Process.GetProcesses();
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Process p in proc.OrderBy(m=>m.ProcessName))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
    }
}
```